# pegar nome de usuário logado com Spring Security

Tags: java-ee, spring-security

Olá, venho aqui pedir ajuda sobre Spring Security.

Gostaria de saber como consigo pegar o nome do usuário logado. Eu utilizo autenticação com login e senha porém quando utilizo o método de busca ele me retorna o login, sendo que preciso pegar o nome do usuário.

```
public String getUsuarioLogado() {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            usuarioLogado = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("usuarioLogado");
            Authentication authentication = (Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (authentication != null) {
               authentication.getName();
            }
            return authentication.getName();

    }
```

Comment: Olá! Poderia nos passar o código que está utilizando para pegar o login? Apenas para termos uma base do que já tentou fazer. Provavelmente você conseguirá a informação que precisa no `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`.

Comment: Obrigado por Responder Dherik

Comment: Quais os campos da classe Usuario? O nome que  quer fica nesta classe?

Answer (score 3):

A maneira [mais fácil](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#obtaining-information-about-the-current-user) de acessar as informações do usuário logado é pelo [`SecurityContextHolder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052882/2387977):

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

String nome;    

if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
    nome = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
    nome = principal.toString();
}
```

Comment: mais essa variavel nome eu passo ela aonde?

Comment: @Dherik, dentro de um método Async isso pode vir a falhar?

Comment: @danilo não vai falhar

Comment: @CíceroRégisOliveira a variável nome foi só para ilustrar como pegar a informação do usuário logado

Comment: Ajudou muito, no meu caso ainda para melhorar no meu sistema, retornei um objeto do tipo Usuario fazendo um cast (Usuario) para converter e deu certo, obrigado pela resposta!